# how to give external css to below given code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.limitChar *').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).text();
    $('div').onfocus(value);
});
```

How to give external css to the `onfocus` value for above code?

Comment: have you tried the `:focus` - pseudoclass? `div:focus`. I am not sure if it works on div-elements though

Comment: There shouldn't be any event named `onfocus` If i am not wrong. Instead you use `.focus` or `.on('focus')` or `.focusin`

Comment: I have tired div:focus  but it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is to use pure CSS.
just add a classname :focus to make it work..
but if due to some conditions you cant try below JS

```
HTML
<input type="text" name="inputOne" />
<input type="text" name="inputTwo" />



   $('input').focus(function(){
        $(this).css("background","green");
    }).
    blur(function(){
        $(this).css("background","white");
    });
```

EDIT:

If you want to do something when div or child elements gets focus

```
$("div").focusin(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFFCC");
});
```